# SQLite storage API Insert statement freezes entire firefox in bootstrapped(Restartless) AddOn

Tags: sqlite, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-restartless

Data to be inserted has just two TEXT columns whose individual length don't even exceed 256.

I initially used `executeSimpleSQL` since I didn't need to get any results.
It worked for simulataneous inserts of upto 20K smoothly i.e. in the bakground no lag or freezing observed.

However, with 0.1 million I could see horrible freezing during insertion.

So, I tried these two,

1. Insert in chunks of 500 records - This didn't work well since even for 20K records it showed visible freezing. I didn't even try with 0.1million.
2. So, I decided to go async and used executeAsync alongwith Bind etc. This also shows visible freezing for just 20K records. This was the whole array being inserted and not in chunks.

   ```
   var dirs = Cc["@mozilla.org/file/directory_service;1"].
              getService(Ci.nsIProperties);
   var dbFile = dirs.get("ProfD", Ci.nsIFile);
   var dbService = Cc["@mozilla.org/storage/service;1"].
              getService(Ci.mozIStorageService);

   dbFile.append('mydatabase.sqlite');

   var connectDB = dbService.openDatabase(dbFile);

   let insertStatement = connectDB.createStatement('INSERT INTO my_table 
                         (my_col_a,my_col_b) VALUES  
                         (:myColumnA,:myColumnB)');
   var arraybind = insertStatement.newBindingParamsArray();

   for (let i = 0; i < my_data_array.length; i++) {
     let params = arraybind.newBindingParams();

     // Individual elements of array have csv

     my_data_arrayTC = my_data_array[i].split(',');

     params.bindByName("myColumnA", my_data_arrayTC[0]);
     params.bindByName("myColumnA", my_data_arrayTC[1]);

     arraybind.addParams(params);
   }

   insertStatement.bindParameters(arraybind);

   insertStatement.executeAsync({
     handleResult: function(aResult) {
       console.log('Results are out');
     },
     handleError: function(aError) {
       console.log("Error: " + aError.message);
     },
     handleCompletion: function(aReason) {
       if (aReason != Components.interfaces.mozIStorageStatementCallback.REASON_FINISHED)
         console.log("Query canceled or aborted!");
       console.log('We are done inserting');
     }
   });

   connectDB.asyncClose(function() {
     console.log('[INFO][Write Database] Async - plus domain data');
   });
   ```

Also, I seem to get the async callbacks after a long time. Usually, `executeSimpleSQL` is way faster than this.If I use SQLite Manager Tool extension to open the DB immediately this is what I get ( as expected )

`SQLiteManager: Error in opening file mydatabase.sqlite - either the file is encrypted or corrupt
Exception Name: NS_ERROR_STORAGE_BUSY
Exception Message: Component returned failure code: 0x80630001 (NS_ERROR_STORAGE_BUSY) [mozIStorageService.openUnsharedDatabase]`

My primary objective was to dump data as big as 0.1 million + and then later on perform reads when needed.

Comment: There is an async version which is the recommended way. In fact, non-async will not get full approval, only preliminary, as it is a performance issue. Check this out - sqlite.jsm - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/Sqlite.jsm - it is fully async.

Comment: @Noitidart I am making use of `executeAsync` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/mozIStorageStatement#executeAsync() which is async too or did I get something wrong there?

Comment: that's correct that's async. Try using sqlite.jsm though, it might not have the issues you are running into. The jsm abstracts away a lot of intricacies.